# Extend link field output on Drupal Twig Template

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

I'm trying to figure out how to extend a common Link Field in Drupal 8 with an HTML entity (like »).
My first try was a preprocess function for the field. Unfortunately I didn't manage to set the `html` option of the link to `true`
Here's how I tried it

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_field(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#field_name'] == 'field_slideshow_link'){
    foreach ($variables['items'] as $idx => $item) {
      $variables['items'][$idx]['content']['#title'] = $variables['items'][$idx]['content']['#title'] . " <span>&raquo;</span>";
      $variables['items'][$idx]['content']['#url']->setOption('html', true);
    }
  }
}
```

This didn't work. So the only solution I came up with was to manually generate a Link within the template. With just doesn't feel right. Here's how I did it

```
  <a href="{{ node.field_slideshow_link.0.url }}">{{ node.field_slideshow_link.0.title }} <span>&raquo;</span></a>
```

Has anyone an idea how to solve this problem more elegantly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had trouble with this too. Found the following solution

```
$url = [
'#title' => new FormattableMarkup('&@text;', ['@text' => t('raquo')]);
//The rest
];
```

Did this with html elements like span so not sure if it will work with this. Let me know!

Comment: Thanks. This works. Still not sure if it's the right way to do this. But hey still learning Drupal 8

Comment: @JensHeidrich I came to the idea by looking in the source code. When it renders it looks if it's of the SafeMarkup type. If it's not all HTML will be escaped. Please accept this as correct answer to this can be closed